# Charge inside spherical cavity

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

Suppose we have a sphere and a cavity inside which is displaced at a distance $d$ from the center. If a charge $q$ is placed in the center of that cavity, a surface charge $-q$ is induced in the surface of the cavity, and as a result, another charge is induced in the surface of the outer sphere. Is this induced charge uniformly distributed through the outer sphere's surface? If so, why? Would something change if the charge were not put in the center of the cavity but at a distance $d'$ from its center?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Charge inside a sphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119827/)